# Setting a Silverlight App to be WindowLess

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have downloaded the ComponentOne Silverlight controls, and am trying to add the HTMLHost control to one of my UserControls.
When I run the App, I get the message

> To use this control the silverlight plugin must have its 'windowless' Property set to true

Does anyone know how I set this property?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838156(v=VS.95).aspx), you'll need to add this:

```
<param name="windowless" value="bool"/>
```

Complete Example:

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
    <param name="source" value="ClientBin/TestSilverlightStuff.xap"/>
    <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
    <param name="background" value="white" />
        <param name="windowless" value="true"/>
    <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
    <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
    <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" style="text-decoration:none">
        <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
    </a>
</object>
```

Comment: This is actually wrong, it should be `<param name="windowless" value="true"/>`

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838156(VS.95).aspx, in the value = "bool" use true or false.

Comment: @Thanks Amit, I had seen this though, and didn't quite understand how to translate that into my situation. When I try to set the object element I get no <Param> element option.